# Querying a relation in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to extend my site search. You can search for a title or in the description of an offer right now. Every offer has a subject. The subject has a name. I want to search for the subject name, too, but I can't it working.
This is how far I tried:

```
$adverts = Advert::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->active();

  if($search)
    $adverts = $adverts->whereHas('subjects', function($q) use ($search)
    {
      $q->where('name', 'like', '%$search%');
    })
    ->where(function($query) use ($search) {
        $query->where("title", "like", "%$search%");
        $query->orWhere("description", "like", "%$search%");
    })
    ->get();
```

There's nothing broken, but the query does not find any Offers with the subject name like the search.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: I'm pretty sure your `where` after the `whereHas` should be `orWhere`

Comment: In the ```name like``` query you use single quotes while you put a variable name in it. I suggest making double quotes from it or concatenate the variable.

Comment: @Strernd great! I'm going to write an answer so you can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default boolean operator for the `where` function in Laravel is `AND`. That means your code is actually saying:

> Where the name contains $search AND title or the description contains $search

Obviously what you want is an `OR` in there.

So simply change the `where` after `whereAs` to `orWhere`.

```
$adverts = $adverts->whereHas('subjects', function($q) use ($search)
{
  $q->where('name', 'like', '%$search%');
})
->orWhere(function($query) use ($search) {
    $query->where("title", "like", "%$search%");
    $query->orWhere("description", "like", "%$search%");
})
->get();
```